# How to use @Inject ed Spring Environment in @Component constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a utility class to manage some LDAP connections across multiple Spring `@Service`s that connect to the same LDAP instance. The LDAP portions are not that important for this example, but should help for background. Because this is a utility class, I'd like the class to get instantiated automagically by Spring and for the class to immediately configure itself with the application's configured properties. Then, as soon as I need to use the class, I can simply call a `getConnection()` method and receive a fully-configured, ready to use connection.

I have the application configured to be able to use an injected instance of the `org.springframework.core.env.Environment` to retrieve the application's properties, which works successfully in other `@Service` classes, though they are never referenced in a `@Service`'s constructor.

The util class currently looks like:

```
@Component
public class LdapConnectionFactory {


    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    private LdapConnectionPool connectionPool;

    public LdapConnectionFactory() {
        // TODO Support empty/bad configurations
        LdapConnectionConfig ldapConnectionConfig = new LdapConnectionConfig();
        ldapConnectionConfig.setLdapHost(env.getProperty("ldap.hostname"));
        ldapConnectionConfig.setLdapPort(env.getProperty("ldap.port", int.class));
        ldapConnectionConfig.setUseTls(true);
        ldapConnectionConfig.setName(env.getProperty("ldap.managerDn"));
        ldapConnectionConfig.setCredentials(env.getProperty("ldap.managerPassword"));

        DefaultPoolableLdapConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new DefaultPoolableLdapConnectionFactory(ldapConnectionConfig);
        connectionPool = new LdapConnectionPool(poolableConnectionFactory);
    }

    /**
     * Gives a LdapConnection fetched from the pool.
     *
     * @return an LdapConnection object from pool
     * @throws Exception if an error occurs while obtaining a connection from the factory
     */
    public LdapConnection getConnection() throws LdapException {
        return connectionPool.getConnection();
    }
}
```

When run, the Spring initialization fails b/c `env` remains null in the class's constructor, and the `env.getProperty()` calls subsequently throw `NullPointerException`s. How can I code up this class so that I can be sure that the application's properties get properly injected at instantiation time (or immediately thereafter, so that I can be sure that by the time I try to use the class, the `connectionPool` variable has been created and configured)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Spring you can inject dependencies using:

1. constructor
2. field
3. setter method

So, instead of injecting value to the field, you should inject this value using constructor. The simple code may look like this:

```
@Inject
public LdapConnectionFactory(Environment env) {
    //rest your code
}
```

But if you don't want inject value using constructor, you can using a `@PostConstruct` method.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //rest your code from constructor
}
```

Comment: This could work... Elsewhere in the application we inject at the field instead of the constructor. For the sake of consistency, do you know of a way to (or a technical reason why we can't) maintain the field injection style while using the field in a constructor?

Comment: Because before Spring inject value to the field, the object must be created. So Spring first create object, using constructor and then inject value to the field.